# Iphone 2d game development and character animation

Tags: iphone, animation, after-effects, 2d-games

Im working on a 2d game where I do basically have my character  standing in the middle of my iphone stage kicking balls.
I build the character  as a vector (with illustrator) and I want to know if is possible to animate it in after effects and export it in whatever format (I know I should use .png ) I can use in my iphone game..
The character won't have any interaction with the user and it will basically loop (kicking balls) untile the user quit the game.

thanks
Luca

Comment: Which part of this is related to programming?

Comment: im asking how animation for Iphone App can be done apart from png..if that is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible ;) but be careful your picture frames should not be a long animation , you can use `UIImage` to show an animation  , the best format is PNG , so you can do it like this :

```
NSMutableArray* myImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:122] autorelease];
for( int i = 1; i <= 122; i++ ) {
    NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animation_%d.png",i];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed: filename];
    [myImages addObject: image];

}

myAnimation.animationImages = myImages;
[myAnimation setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
myAnimation.animationDuration = 0;
[myAnimation startAnimating];
```

the nubmer 122 is the animation frames .

Comment: THANKS  for the snippet.I just found out I can export images sequence from after effects so this is going to be my solution

Comment: Just so you know, this is a bad solution since it will crash your device when all memory is consumed. There are many ways to do it better, but the advice above is literally the worst possible solution as it holds all decoded image data in memory at the same time! A better solution, for example, is to export to Quicktime with the Animation codec from After Effects as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36027166/763355