# Implementing Perfectly Timed Animations

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, after-effects, cakeyframeanimation

## Creating Perfectly "up to spec" Animations

I'm working with a designer right now that likes to work a lot with After Effects. They create beautiful, well timed animations that look great, but I'm having trouble actually implementing the designs.

I can make everything look perfect, as in everything is the right size, shape, color, etc., but I can't get the movements to feel perfect, like they are in the spec. I can try my best to eyeball it, and tweak my animation parameters until things look close enough to the original design, but this isn't very satisfying. All of that tweaking and recompiling is super time consuming, and not very fun, and in the end things don't always feel correct as I can only approximate the timing functions.

Are there any tools that make implementing After Effects animations in iOS easier?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a look at my animation library for iOS. [iOS Animation Examples](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html) With this native library you can import Quicktime video data using the Animation codec and convert that data with exact timing already defined by the animators. This ability to export directly from After Effects can really save you a lot of time.

Comment: Is this for playing back video exported from an After Effects composition in an app? I'm looking more for a way of extracting the keyframe timing information from an after effects file so I can create animation objects that have the same keyframe and timing information in them.

Comment: Yes, it is for playing After Effects exported lossless video with exact timings. The thing you describe does not exist and cannot be implemented since there is no animation interchange format to support it and After Effects does not export anything that could be used for this purpose. Feel free to build your own though.